# Events in pygame do not work

Tags: python, events, pygame

I'm using python 3.4.3.
Having some trouble with pygame events.
After pressing mentioned keys (Up, Down, Left or Right), 99% of the time, program does not react. Spamming one (or multiple) keys seems to be the only way to remedy this, but even that is unreliable.

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1024, 768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
g = pygame.image.load(
        'X:\\Projects\\Rogue\\Game Project\\src\\img\\Tiles\grass.JPG')
player = pygame.image.load('untitled.PNG')
pygame.display.set_caption('WINDOW_NAME')

run = True
def resolve(x,y):#x=32 y=20
    return (x*32, y*32)

def get_tiles():
    tiles = []
    for y in range(0,20):
        for x in range(0,32):
            tiles.append(resolve(x,y))
    return tiles

p = [5,5]

def draw_player(p):
    screen.blit(player, resolve(p[0],p[1]))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def move(direction):
    if direction == 'U':
        if p[1]-1 < 0:
            print('fail')
        else:
            p[1] = p[1] - 1
    elif direction == 'D':
        if p[1] + 1 > 20:
            print('fail')
        else:
            p[1] = p[1] + 1
    elif direction == 'L':
        if p[0] - 1 < 0:
            print('fail')
        else:
            p[0] = p[0] - 1
    elif direction == 'R':
        if p[0] + 1 > 32:
            print('fail')
        else:
            p[0] = p[0] + 1

def event_handler():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print('event:',event)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                print('fish')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move('U')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move('D')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move('L')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move('R')
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print('a')
                print(pygame.display.get4_driver())
                for item in pygame.display.list_modes():
                    print(item)

def render(sprites):
    for item in sprites:
        screen.blit(g,item)

from random import randint

while run:
    #if len(pygame.event.get()) > 0:
    print(p)
    print(pygame.event.get())
    event_handler()
    render(get_tiles())
    draw_player(p)
    #screen.fill(255,255,255)#wipe to black
    pygame.display.flip()#screen updates all areas that have been blited
    clock.tick(30)#30 FPS for now

pygame.quit()
```

Also, `pygame.quit()` does nothing for me, hence the part where escape kills the program straight away.

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fFxy6isW
Something like this is typical

Comment: Get rid of that print().  You're clearing your event queue *before* you run your event handler!

Comment: Ah. Much better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the print(pygame.event.get()). Get rid of the or in the event loop because you are just checking the same thing again so it wont do anything and the if statement to check the mouse button should be outside the if statement for checking for key-downs.